# Reference field's default function in Django model's method

Tags: django, django-models

There is a model with a field that should be auto-populated with a fixed-length random identifier:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def get_random_string_fixed():
    return get_random_string(length=20)

class Post(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(unique=True, default=get_random_string_fixed)
```

In order to unsure that the generate value is indeed unique, I want regenerate it in the save method, if such value already exists:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        while Post.objects.filter(identifier=self.identifier).exists():
            self.identifier = get_random_string_fixed()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem with this implementation is that `get_random_string_fixed` is hardcoded in the `save()` method. If at some point I decide to choose a different default function for this field, I'll have to change it in several places, which is a bad practice.

Is there a way of referencing the function assigned to the `default` attribute of a field in a model's method, without hardcoding the name of the function?

Comment: Create a function named `identifier_default` and use that instead. You can then delegate the actual functionality to whatever function you like.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed an option, but I hope there is a way to get it via something like `class.field.default`.

Comment: why your `while` isn't placed inside the function of `get_random_string_fixed()`?

Comment: @SancaKembang because this is not the job of the `get_random_string_fixed()` function. This function can be used in any other field/model.

Comment: I think it should possible, maybe like this: http://pastebin.com/w9MAKmwu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [introspection API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/) to do that:

```
Post._meta.get_field("identifier").default
```

That said, I don't see much point in having a `default` at all. You're overriding it in `save()` anyway, and it's a bit misleading since it's not *actually* the default.

Also note that your algorithm still has failure cases. With default transaction isolation levels it won't prevent two transactions from writing the same value at the same time. Of course, that's extremely unlikely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Can you elaborate more on the coincident isolated transactions? How can one protect against those?

Comment: By default, transactions only see the state of the database at the time that they are opened. So if another transaction saves value `X` after you've opened your transaction, you will not see `X` in your search. When you try to commit your transaction, though, it will fail because of the uniqueness constraint. Dealing with these issues is not straightforward, but you can look into *optimistic concurrency* for a possible solution.

Comment: But my advice is— *don't worry about detecting these conflicts*. The whole point of using UUIDs (which is basically what you're doing) is that the chance of a collision is so [astronomically low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) that you can simply ignore it. While we're at it, why don't you just use the built-in [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)?

Comment: Because this `identifier` will be presented to users, and should be short, about 8-10 characters long. Ideally, it should be like short versions of Git commit ids. But `UUIDField` is too long for this purpose.

Comment: Git is a great example of my point. Git ids are 40-character ids that are not checked for uniqueness because the odds of a conflict are so low. The short version is just a simpler way to present and use those ids. Feel free to do the same. Or, just use a regular auto-incrementing integer (nothing's shorter than `1`). Or hash that unique integer into a string of 8-10 characters if you prefer. We've come quite far from your original question, but my point is that there are probably better ways to achieve your goal here.